# Swift 3: UISwipeGestureRecognizer works on View but not on ViewContainer

Tags: ios, swift3, storyboard, xcode8, uigesturerecognizer

I'm quite new to App development (having a coding background though) with Swift 3 and Xcode 8.3.3. I have found some Objective-C answers which I don't quite understand and don't know how to implement it in Swift.

**Here's what I have:**

1. [Document Outline, Storyboard & Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6j7t.jpg)
2. [the OnboardingViewController Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGuUL.png)

**What it does**

The *swipeOnView method works like a charm* and I know that this is correct due to the "2. Document Outline" as the "Container View" is a child of the View and doesn't receive gestures.

BUT: as soon as the "Container View" is covering (or should - it's half of the height due to testing) the entire screen, it seems that it prevents the UIView to receive gestures -> both methods are rendering useless -> which, again...is correct and I kind of get it.

**What I want it to do**

*I want to have the swipeOnContainerView method working* but I wasn't able to figure out how to tell the controller to "listen" only to the container's view gestures and disregard the "parent" UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by myself and here's how:

Step 1: add an Outlet for each GestureRecognizer i.e. @IBOutlet var swipeLeftGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

Step 2: in viewDidLoad() add a delegate for each Outlet i.e. swipeLeftGestureRecognizer.delegate = self

Step 3: change the return value of func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) to true

Step 4: connect the Referencing Outlet to the UIView / SubView in question

Step 5: add IBActions to each GestureRecognizer

done